# Match all emails having first letter in lowercase using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find only those email addresses from the string whose email satisfies the condition.

**Condition: Email must have first character in lowercase.**

```
Example : abc123@xyz.com #Satisfies
Example : Abc123@xyz.com #Not Satisfies
```

**CODE:**

```
import re
str = ''' 
FIRSTEMAIL@gmail.com    
secondemail@gmail.com
Thirdemail@gmail.com
fourthEmail@gmail.com
'''

pattern = r'[a-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+[@]+[a-z]+\.+[a-z]+'

output = re.findall(pattern,str)
print output
```

**Expected Output:**

```
secondemail@gmail.com
fourthEmail@gmail.com
```

**Actual Output:**

```
secondemail@gmail.com
hirdemail@gmail.com   #Problem
fourthEmail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as that (you need to add a word boundary `\b` before the lower case letters):

```
\b[a-z]\S*@\S+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/OFMmQL/2).

---

`\b` ensures a boundary between word and non-word characters and is a zero-width assertion (meaning it does not consume any characters on its own).

Comment: The correct regex I think should include(at end) `+\.+[a-z]+` as a part of validation

Comment: @ZahidKhan: The dot is **not** mandatory in an email address, see: [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples);

Answer (score 0):

It not only ensures the first letter is in small letters but also validates the emails are as per *Expected Output:*

```
pattern = r'\b[a-z]\S*@\S+\.\S+'
```

1. `\b[a-z]` ensures first letter is lowercase.

> example: a

2. `\S*@` ensures string  has **@** at the end.

> example: a@

3. `\S+\.`ensures string must be of length atleast 1 and has **.** at the end.

> example a@gmail.

4. `\S+` ensures that string must be atleast of length 1.

> example a@gmail.com

Comment: Your regex doesn't match `me@localhost` that is valid. Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: 1. This regex perfectly matches my expected output

Comment: Sure, for your specific case. But @Jan answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55109535/372239 is simpler and better.

Comment: I have no problem in accepting @Jan answer's as accepted but I think we hardly will see any email in real world as `identifierpart@localhost` I never have seen any though its valid.